# How can I limit my cloudsearch to a specific field using Boto?

Tags: python, boto, amazon-cloudsearch

I need to do a cloudsearch on only one of my domain's index fields. For example, I need all of the results where 'title' contains 'star wars'. Is this possible using Boto?

According to the [AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html), you need to utilize the 'q.options' parameter:

```
q=star wars&q.options={fields: ['title']}
```

However, it appears that Boto doesn't support that parameter:

```
def search(self, q=None, bq=None, rank=None, return_fields=None,
               size=10, start=0, facet=None, facet_constraints=None,
               facet_sort=None, facet_top_n=None, t=None):
```

Is it possible to search by only one field using Boto?

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using the boto cloudsearch2 API (note the '2'), which is equivalent to the AWS CloudSearch version 2013-01-01 and has an *options* param.

```
search(q=None, parser=None, fq=None, rank=None, return_fields=None,
           size=10, start=0, facet=None, highlight=None, sort=None,
           partial=None, options=None)
```

The doc for the options param:

> options (str) – Options for the query parser specified in parser.
>   Specified as a string in JSON format. {fields: ['title^5',
>   'description']}

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudsearch2.html